# Triggering a Workflow When a Folder is Created and not A File?

Tags: workflow, folder

I'm new to workflows, so please excuse the novice question.

I set up a workflow on a document library configured to send an email when a new item is created.  When I create a new document in this library, the email gets sent as expected.  However, when I create a folder in this library, the workflow doesn't run.  If I look at Workflow Status for the new folder, I don't see the workflow attached.

Is there anything special I need to do to configure this Workflow to kick-off when a folder is created and not just items?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The workflow will kick off when the item is created in the folder.

The better option is to not use folders unless you have special permissions going on or are working with huge document libraries.  The clever use of metadata can get you the folder structure you want without actually using them.

With all that said, I haven't had a need to execute a workflow based on the creation of a folder.  In the conditions of the workflow you might be able to put a condition in there, if Content Type equals Folder (do something).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SharePoint 2007 and creating a workflow using SharePoint designer then workflows are not triggered when folders are created. This is a known limitation.

Try creating an event receiver, Visual studio workflow or a third party tool such as Nintex workflow.